# awk to extract specific pattern in file based on variable match

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to extract the value of `RSTRING` based on where the value of another variable `$VCF` is found in a `file`. The value of `$VCF` is already extracted and the `RSTRING` is currently all lines starting with `R_2019`. What I am trying to get is `RSTRING` be set based on where `$VCF` was found. Thank you :).

**file**

```
xxx_0000 19-0004-La-Fi
xxx_0001 19-0005-Last-Firs
xxx_0003 19-0008-LastN-FirstN
xxx_0005 190320-Control
R_2019_00_00_xxxx-000-v5.6_xxxxx

xxx_0007 19-0000-LastName-FirstName
xxx_0009 19-0001-Las-Fir
xxx_0011 190319-Control
R_2019_00_00_xxxx-00-v5.6_xxxxx
```

If `$VCF=19-0008-LastN-FirstN`

**desired**

```
RSTRING=R_2019_00_00_xxxx-000-v5.6_xxxxx
```

If `$VCF=19-0008-Las-Fir`

**desired**

```
RSTRING=R_2019_00_00_xxxx-00-v5.6_xxxxx
```

**awk**

```
awk -v ref="$VCF" 'match($0, ref) {print "$RSTRING"}' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. reading the file line-by-line, set a boolean flag when you find the VCF and then print the *next* RSTRING:

   ```
   awk -v ref="$VCF" '
       $0 ~ ref {have_vcf = 1}
       have_vcf && /^R_2019/ {print; have_vcf = 0}
   ' file
   ```
2. read the file by paragraphs. If the current record contains the VCF, print the last field of the record:

   ```
   awk -F '\n' -v RS="" -v ref="$VCF" '$0 ~ ref {print $NF}' file
   ```